# Context (this) in an event in the structure of boilerplate

Tags: jquery, boilerplate

I have this plugin with the structure of boilerplate. My problem is to create the event 'controlEventoKeyUp'. 
Be able to access the methods of the plugin, I had to ignore the plugin parameter `bind('keyup',_{_plugin:_this_},_controlEventoKeyUp)`.
This solved my problem but I found a tidy way of doing this.

Can another solution there be with this model?

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    var pluginName = 'controlLenInput',
        defaults = {
            maxLen: 100,
            displanCantidadActual: null,
            textUppercase: false
        };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin(element, options) {

        this.element = element;

        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        this.init();
    };

    Plugin.prototype.init = function () {

        $(this.element)
            .bind('keyup', { plugin: this }, controlEventoKeyUp)
            .trigger('keyup');
    };

    Plugin.prototype.asignarValorActual = function () {

        $(this.options.displanCantidadActual)
            .html('<span>' + (this.options.maxLen - $(this.element).val().length) + '</span>&nbsp;<span>caracteres pendientes</span>');

    };

    var controlEventoKeyUp = function (event) {

        var _plugin = event.data.plugin;

        if (_plugin.options.maxLen < $(this).val().length) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, _plugin.options.maxLen));
        }
        else {
            _plugin.asignarValorActual();
        }

        if (_plugin.options.textUppercase) { 
            $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
        }

    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
            }
        });
    }

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking over the boilerplate template, I could see that calling plugin, is recorded in "data" the instance of the plugin:

```
$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
```

then, to retrieve the instance of the plugin for this element, simply, in the event, I get back it this way:

```
var plugin = $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName);
```

so then would be the function of the event:

```
var controlEventoKeyUp = function (event) {

    var _plugin = $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName);

    if (_plugin.options.maxLen < $(this).val().length) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, _plugin.options.maxLen));
    }
    else {
        _plugin.asignarValorActual();
    }

    if (_plugin.options.textUppercase) { 
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    }

}
```

**Edit**

As fires a "trigger" event, when I access the plugin with "$. data" creates an error, because it still is not there already.
change so as to keep the plugin. in this way, I can access the plugin already loaded without error.

```
// The actual plugin constructor
function Plugin(element, options) {

    this.element = element;

    this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;

    this.element['plugin_' + pluginName] = this;
    this.init();
};

//...

var controlEventoKeyUp = function (event) {

    var _plugin = this['plugin_' + pluginName];

    if (_plugin.options.maxLen < $(this).val().length) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, _plugin.options.maxLen));
    }
    else {
        _plugin.asignarValorActual();
    }

    if (_plugin.options.textUppercase) { 
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    }

}
```